# Email tracking algorithm without explicit embedded URL

Tags: html, email

I'm trying to understand how can the html code below be used to track an email.

I understand that usually a small 1x1 pixel when retrieved from a server generates an alarm that tells when the email was read. But in this case there is no explicit server URL and the gif image is embedded directly using base64 encoding, so how is the connection to the external server established?

I'm using mailtrack.

```html
<img width=3D"=
0" height=3D"0" alt=3D"" style=3D"display:flex" src=3D"data:image/gif;base6=
4,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
<img width=3D"0=
" height=3D"0" class=3D"mailtrack-img" alt=3D"" style=3D"display:flex" src=
=3D"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs3D=
"                 ><div class=3D"gmail_quote">
```